# Observable timeout logic: migration to RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm slowly moving my application from RxJava 1 to RxJava 2.
Everything works fine after having updated all the code, except for one use case and I'm kind of pretty lost at the moment, I guess I need to go back to the document to get it properly.

The application loads a collection of `Asset` from the network and it this operation takes from than x ms, it displays a loading animation. Then when the data is retrieved, animation is stopped/removed and data displayed.

This what I had with RxJava 1 and which was working:

```
getAssetsSubscription = new GetAssetsUseCase().execute()
                    .publish(new Func1<Observable<List<Asset>>, Observable<List<Asset>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<List<Asset>> call(Observable<List<Asset>> o) {
                            return o.timeout(LOADING_VIEW_THRESHOLD_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Asset>>() {
                                         @Override
                                         public List<Asset> call() throws Exception {
                                             if (isAdded()) {
                                                 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void run() {
                                                         setLoadingViewVisibility(true);
                                                     }
                                                 });
                                             }
                                             return null;
                                         }
                                     }
                                )
                            ).ignoreElements().mergeWith(o);
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Asset>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // Do things...
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // Do things...
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Asset> assets) {
                    // Do things...
                }
            });
```

And this is my "translation" to RxJava 2: with this, the data is never displayed, `onComplete` is always called, but `onNext` never. This is also the case when the timeout is not triggered.

```
disposables.add(new GetAssetsUseCase().execute().publish(new Function<Observable<List<Asset>>,
                    ObservableSource<List<Asset>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<Asset>> apply(Observable<List<Asset>> listObservable) throws
                        Exception {
                    return listObservable.timeout(LOADING_VIEW_THRESHOLD_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                            Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Asset>>() {
                                @Override
                                public List<Asset> call() throws Exception {
                                    if (isAdded()) {
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                setLoadingViewVisibility(true);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                }
                            })
                    ).ignoreElements().mergeWith(Completable.fromObservable(listObservable)).toObservable();
                }
            })
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Asset>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // Do things...
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // Do things...
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Asset> assets) {
                    // Do things...
                }
            }));
```

Comment: have you considered replacing `getActivity().runOnUiThread()` with `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` like in any reasonable RxJava example that doesn't do random threading outside of Rx?

Comment: `.ignoreElements().mergeWith(Completable).toObservable()` - This observable will only ever invoke `onError` or `onComplete`. Elements are ignored so `onNext` will never happen.

Comment: @Kiskae yes, that's what I see, strange because it was working (or not?) before these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code used `Observable#mergeWith(Observable)`.
Since RxJava2 narrows types where appropriate this changed in your revised code to `Completable.mergeWith(Completable)`.

To get the same behavior as the old code you need to change the order of operations:

- from `.ignoreElements().mergeWith(Completable.fromObservable(listObservable)).toObservable()`
- to `.ignoreElements().<List<Asset>>toObservable().mergeWith(listObservable)`

since `Completable.fromObservable(...)` is basically equivalent to `Observable#ignoreElements()`.

In addition the `return null;` will probably cause problems with RxJava2 since the contract specifies there can be no `null` values in the event stream. Consider replacing the `Observable.fromCallable(...)` with `Completable.fromRunnable(...).toObservable()`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I came up after checking the docs, even if it's still not 100% clear, but I'll go through the RxJava2 docs again. One small details: correct change is `ignoreElements().<List<Asset>>toObservable().mergeWith(listObservable)`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your callable returns `null`, which means it is a terminal event.

```
@Override
public List<Asset> call() throws Exception {
    if(isAdded()) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setLoadingViewVisibility(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
}
```

Should be

```
@Override
public List<Asset> call() throws Exception {
    if(isAdded()) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // TODO: move after `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setLoadingViewVisibility(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not getting the `onNext` called. It's not called when the timeout is not triggered.